Consuming today's Twitter (X) home feed on a future date
I like to remain updated with "For You" tab of Twitter/X, but sometimes I get too busy and don't get time to catch-up. Is there a tool/utility that can store some fixed number of Tweets from my feed when I tell it, and store them somewhere so that I can read those Tweets later?
PS1: I'm not looking into Twitter API because it seems too expensive ($100 pm) for this.
PS2: I'm not looking into the bookmark feature of Twitter either because not only it is slow to bookmark 1 by 1, but also distracting to go that way.
